# A girl lost in a strange animated city

Tags: identify-this-movie

From what I recall, a girl who is about twenty years old finds herself in a strange and gloomy  stop-frame animated city.  A very distinct scene, which should identify the film, involves the girl being captured by a creature described as follows.  It was like the walking skeleton of a long four-legged creature about the size of a bus.  Apparently the girl broke some rule and this creature clamped it's ribcage around her and trotted her off to jail.

If I had to guess a year, it would be between 1996 and 2006.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This sounds very much like [MirrorMask](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0366780/), a wonderful movie. It isn't French or Eastern European, but it does have some bohemian style to it (a bit like [The City of Lost Children](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112682/)). So it's not surprising that you might recall the movie like that.

The creature is actually a compilation of several creatures, with the ability to use their stilt-caterpillar shape as a walking prison.

Here are some pictures to jog your memory:
[image]

The visual style was *very* distinctive, and I'm pretty certain this is the one you are thinking of.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that MirrorMask is based on a Neil Gaiman story.

Comment: Indeed, Neil is also a solid influence on the movie itself, and numerous of his drawings and sketches can be seen. :]